# Generating a desired GUID in C#

Tags: c#, guid

Is this possible somehow to generate a GUID in C#, that mostly corresponds to something i need.

**For ex:**

I have some version variable : **02.10.0020**

And i need to generate a GUID which closely corresponds to the version variable.

Something like **{02102012-98EF-41F6-96FF-2935C306E479}**

Is this possible ??

Comment: um... then uniqueness couldn't be guaranteed, hence it wouldn't qualify as a GUID...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not directly possible.

You can generate a GUID then convert to a string and replace the first section with the wanted format.

This does mean that you are reducing the entropy of the GUID.

Comment: Thanks, I know i can tweak it according to my needs using string.replace. I was curious if there's exists a possibility where i could do that :)

Comment: @this-Me - "I was curious if there's exists a possibility where i could do that". What does that mean???

Comment: I meant a straight-forward way... Guid.NewGuid("#2012#"); where the #2012# indicates a pattern of GUID i want

Comment: @this-Me - No, no such thing, as it would be completely against the design goals of GUIDs.

Answer (score 9):

While you could create a new GUID and replace the first section with your version, I wouldn't recommend it. That's not what the GUID was designed for. You'd be better off having both a GUID and a version.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you could create a new Guid with `Guid.NewGuid()` and then use its value in conjunction with your data to create another new Guid.

This perverts the Guid, however, and you should consider if this is truly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I've used for things like this is to simply append the Guid to your version:

```
string myGuid = string.format("02.10.0020-{0}", System.Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: No, i'm not looking for making it more unique by tagging the extra version information. I just wanted to know if there exists a possibility where i could get a GUID the pattern closing matching to my requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string value and convert it to guid. On the other hand, you can never be sure that this guid is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I did this code (use LinqPad) that generate a guid from a custom length string by using md5 hash system.

```
void Main()
{
    Guid.NewGuid().Dump();
    ParseCustom("ID123456").Dump();
    ParseCustom("ID12345678").Dump();
}

private static Guid ParseCustom(string input)
{
    var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    var guidString = ToHexString(hashBytes);
    return new Guid(guidString);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private static char ToHexDigit(int i)
{
    if (i < 10)
        return (char)(i + '0');
    return (char)(i - 10 + 'A');
}

public static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
{
    var chars = new char[bytes.Length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        chars[2 * i] = ToHexDigit(bytes[i] / 16);
        chars[2 * i + 1] = ToHexDigit(bytes[i] % 16);
    }

    var guid = new string(chars)
        .Insert(8, "-")
        .Insert(13, "-")
        .Insert(18, "-")
        .Insert(23, "-");
    return guid.ToLower();
}
```